# Grab LDAP Attribute from stdin in Python

Tags: python, text, ldap

I've got an LDAP query and I'm not well versed in text-processing in Python. I'm sending it into my script via stdin and I can read it out, however given that it reads as a single line I am a little more lost as to how to grab the value of say the protocol. Given protocol=HTTP, I want to store the value after the delimiter.

My stdin looks like (but not exactly):

```
discover-repository-location=null, File Name=null, date-detected=Tue Jun11 12:44:14 UTC 2013, endpoint-machine-name=null, incident-id=545527, sender-ip=12.1.141.87, sender-email=WinNT://tmpdm/tmpcmp, Assigned To=null, sender-port=-null, endpoint-domain-name=null, Business Unit=null, endpoint-dos-volume-name=null, file-access-date=null, date-sent=Tue Jun 11 12:44:14 UTC 2013, endpoint-file-name=null, file-modified-by=null, Country=null, Manager Email=null, plugin-chain-id=1, discover-server=null, data-owner-name=null, Dismissal Reason=null, Last Name=null, First Name=null, Phone=null, subject=HTTP incident, Sender Email=null, UserID=null, endpoint-user-name=null, endpoint-volume-name=null, discover-name=null, discover-content-root-path=null, data-owner-email=null, file-create-date=null, endpoint-application-name=null, Employee Code=null, Region=null, Manager First Name=null, path=null, endpoint-application-path=null, Manager Last Name=null, Department=null, discover-location=null, protocol=HTTP, Resolution=null, file-owner=null, Postal Code=null, endpoint-file-path=null, Title=null, discover-extraction-date=null, Script-attribute=null, Manager Phone=null, file-created-by=null, file-owner-domain=nul
```

And I can assure that I can find it by:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
     if 'protocol' in line:
         print "Protocol found"
```

Any ideas or pointers on my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line_dict
for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = line.split(",")
    line_dict = dict(map(str.strip,part.split("=")) for part in parts)
    print line_dict['protocol']
```

to be fair I didnt test it so there may be some minor syntax errors but something like that is probably what you want.  however if you just wanted protocol

```
import re
for line in sys.stdin:
     if 'protocol' in line:
         print re.findall("protocol\s*=([^,]*)",line)
```

Comment: Excellent. I didn't even think of using regex to solve my problem. That simplifies the process of multiple for loops of spliting the text. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that it creates a list rather than a single variable. Great if I'm expecting 'protocol' to be listed in a LDAP query more than once, but that doesn't happen. Still works fine of course.

Comment: you can easily use re.search ... but then it will return a match object instead of a string ...

Comment: Yeah. Well since I only expect one instance to show up in the LDAP query I just set protocoltmp=re.findall(...) and then protocol = protocoltmp[0] and it gives me a string value.